What references to other Tatsuki Fujimoto works, like Chainsaw Man, appear in Look Back?
After watching the 2024 anime film Look Back, adapted from Tatsuki Fujimoto's manga of the same name, I learned that Fujimoto also created the popular manga Chainsaw Man (though I haven't read the manga or seen its anime adaptation).
In a discussion on Reddit /r/anime, I've seen people mention that Shark Kick, one of the mangas-within-the-story in Look Back, is meant to be a reference to Chainsaw Man, though I'm not clear on how exactly it's a reference.
I'd like to understand how Shark Kick references Chainsaw Man, and I'm also curious about any other Easter eggs or references in Look Back that connect to Fujimoto's other works like Chainsaw Man, Fire Punch, or Goodbye, Eri.

My experience with Fujimoto's works extends to Look Back, Chainsaw Man and the first volume of Fire Punch, so my knowledge is not comprehensive, but here are the references I noticed.
Shark Kick is a callback to Fire Punch in its name, along with the cover art pose being a reference to one of the volumes of Chainsaw Man: 
Shark Kick goes on hiatus after its 11th volume, much like Chainsaw Man.
The door that Kyomoto is painting during the alternate timeline is a door that Denji, the titular Chainsaw Man, dreams of multiple times: 
During the montage of Kyomoto and Fujino hanging out, they visit a movie thater which plays a movie with this screen: 
This is a reference to the famous last panel of Goodbye Eri: 
Fujino and Kyomoto could be said to be a reference in themselves, as taking the first and last parts of their names and combining them results in Fujimoto, the mangaka of all the works referenced.
